# make twiiter bootstrap columns width smaller

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, I have spent hours on this trying to get the classes to manipulate like I need.

However, the columns are giving too much space between the days.

Here is what I have thus far. http://tinypic.com/r/2hx0jnp/8

```
<div class="row hours_bg">
    <h4>Hours</h4>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <br />
        Open
        <br />
        <br />
        Close
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10 hours_div">

    <?php foreach($days as $day):
        $daylow = strtolower($day);
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-3"><?php echo $day[0]; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-3">
                <span id="pre_open_<?php echo $daylow ?>">

                 <?php echo isset($location['open_' . $daylow]) ? $location['open_' . $daylow] : '' ?>
                </span> <br />
                <span id="pre_close_<?php echo $daylow ?>">

                <?php echo isset($location['close_' . $daylow]) ? $location['close_' . $daylow] : '' ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

This is the result I need: http://tinypic.com/r/2ikeaee/8

I really have tried everything I know.

I can move the hours margin -left pixels to not overlap the open and close text. However, again the ending s or Sunday will cut off because the columns are too wide.

I do have some other css:

```
.hours_bg {
background: #fff;

}
.hours_div {
margin-left: -50px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: A `row` needs to be within a `container` class. 
This row is then broken into 12 segments `col`
After you finish each segment of 12 cols you should create a new row.

Comment: I am not following you completely. Here is what I tried. Can you give me an example. Thanks. http://laravel.io/bin/48ela

Answer (score 0):

A `row` needs to be within a `container` class.

This `row` is then broken into 12 segments col After you finish each segment of 12 `cols` you should create a new `row`.

Your code should be simular to this although i have not tested it:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <h4 class='hours_bg'>Hours</h4>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <br />
            Open
            <br />
            <br />
            Close
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-10 hours_div">

            <?php foreach($days as $day):
                    $daylow = strtolower($day);
            ?>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-3"><?php echo $day[0]; ?></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-3">
                    <span id="pre_open_<?php echo $daylow ?>">

                     <?php echo isset($location['open_' . $daylow]) ? $location['open_' . $daylow] : '' ?>
                    </span> <br />
                    <span id="pre_close_<?php echo $daylow ?>">

                    <?php echo isset($location['close_' . $daylow]) ? $location['close_' . $daylow] : '' ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Notice how each row will contain 12 col total.

REF : [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Stepping away from the div, perhaps a table would be more suited ?>

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
        <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>OPEN</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CLOSE</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
      <td>9AM</td>
    </tr>          
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s003a3xj/) with static content its much easier to see whats going on..

Comment: I tried your code and the days disappeared. I then took off the hours_div class and they appeared. Here is what I tried http://laravel.io/bin/JdL7a and here is what the updated looks like http://tinypic.com/r/yp8cg/8

Comment: @Billy I have added another option to the answer.. might be more suited for this particular problem.. http://jsfiddle.net/s003a3xj/
You should still read more on the bootstrap frameworks structure to see what you're missing. Being given the answer wont help you! :(

Comment: is this table responsive?